# HTML in a JLabel not displaying correctly

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

My JPanel using BorderLayout was working well until I decided to add a JLabel that had HTML in its text. I've spent several hours double checking with people that have had the same problems, but no fix. When I comment out the lines dealing with this JLabel, everything works fine. I tried using a JTextArea instead, but I have had the same problem.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

JFrame jFrame;
JPanel backgroundPanel;
JLabel multiLineTextLabel;
JLabel statusLabel;

int xValue = 1000;

Gui() {
    jFrame = new JFrame("Frame Name");
    jFrame.setSize(1200, 600);
    jFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    backgroundPanel = new JPanel();
    backgroundPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    String htmlString = "<html>Word1<br>Word2</html>";
    multiLineTextLabel = new JLabel(htmlString);

    statusLabel = new JLabel("Some Text");

    jFrame.add(backgroundPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jFrame.add(multiLineTextLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    jFrame.add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    jFrame.setFocusable(true);
    jFrame.addKeyListener(this);

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
    //Won't be using
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        xValue -= 20;
        statusLabel.setText("You are clicking left");
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        xValue += 20;
        statusLabel.setText("You are clicking right"); //You are "pressing" right
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        statusLabel.setText("You are clicking A"); //You are "pressing" A
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        statusLabel.setText("You are clicking S");
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
    {
        jFrame.setVisible(false); 
        jFrame.dispose();
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_P)
    {
        String positionString = new String("Your position/XValue = " + xValue);

        statusLabel.setText(positionString);
    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    //Won't be using
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Gui go = new Gui();
}
}
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work inside of JLabels.

Comment: what does private Component controlKeyPanel; do ? you added to your layout yet did not make any object like JPanel or whatever ? you ahve this label multiLineTextLabel but you did not add it to your layout?

Comment: when I added  multiLineTextLabel to your layout, it works perfectly

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to edit that. It's just supposed to say multiLineTextLabel instead.

Comment: what is your issue right now cuz it works perfectly for me?

Comment: The 1200x600 frame is completely gray. If I replace the html text with just a simple string, it works. But for some reason, the html just makes the entire screen blank.

Comment: no it is not just push left, right, A or S, you see it changes color

Comment: Oh, you are right! That's weird how you need to push one of the keys for everything to appear. I guess this is a separate matter. I'm guessing it has to do with the order that I add the elements to the frame and how they get shown. Thanks!

Comment: so ur issue is solved?

Comment: Yep, the html works.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as you post it.

Comment: You are setting your frame visible before adding any components to it. Setting it visible should be the last thing you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is performing correct, but my guess is you do not know the difference between clicking and pushing buttons because in your `keyPressed` function you said  **"You are clicking right"** which doe snot make sense. You should chenge it to **Your are pushing right arrow**.

You just need to push either right, left, S , or A button to see your code is doing what you want.

Another point, before you did not add `multiLineTextLabel` to your `JFrame`, but when I told you, everything works as you expected

One point about `JTextArea`, you could do this

```
 String htmlString = "<html>Word1\n<br>Word2</html>";
 JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(htmlString);
 jFrame.add(jta, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

so your html code works as you want

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the frame visible at the very end. I was accidently setting visible, then adding all the components.